# GeoFire Swift 3 - Saving and Updating Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm trying to store coordinates into Firebase Database using GeoFire.

I'm unsure how to update the new coordinates as they will be changed/updated every second.  With the `childByAutoId`, it is generating a new unique ID for each Bike.

How do I reference this unique Bike ID?  For instance, the user would be called by `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid`. Is this possible?

```
 let geofireRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Bike").childByAutoId()
 let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)

 var data = geoFire?.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: userIncrementLat, longitude: userIncrementLong), forKey: "BikeId")
```

My Firebase Database Structure will look like...

```
 Root
 1. Bike
 2.  UniqueUID Number (Firebase)
 3.   BikeId
 4.    g
       l
 5.     0:
        1:
```

Comment: Also how would the values be retrieved?  I'm just struggling to understand how I would call this unique ID.

Answer (score 6):

This is my Firebase DB structure for update users location by time and retrive the nearby users to show on map:

```
db-root
"users" : {
    <userUID> : {
        "someKey" : "someValue",
        ...
    }
}
"users_location" : {
    <userUID> : {
        <geofireData> ...
    }
}
```

Vars to use:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref.child("users_location"))
```

To update logged user location:

```
func updateUserLocation() {

    if let myLocation = myLocation {

        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
        geoFire!.setLocation(myLocation, forKey: userID) { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                debugPrint("An error occured: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Saved location successfully!")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

To find nearby user I use the `findNearbyUsers` function. It' useful to find the nearby users and save into `nearbyUsers` array the UID key of the the users. The `observeReady` function is executed after the query completion and uses the UID to retrieve the users details (I use this to show users details on map).

```
func findNearbyUsers() {

    if let myLocation = myLocation {

        let theGeoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref.child("users_location"))
        let circleQuery = theGeoFire!.query(at: myLocation, withRadius: radiusInMeters/1000)

        _ = circleQuery!.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in

            if !self.nearbyUsers.contains(key!) && key! != FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid {
                self.nearbyUsers.append(key!)
            }

        })

        //Execute this code once GeoFire completes the query!
        circleQuery?.observeReady({

            for user in self.nearbyUsers {

                self.ref.child("users/\(user)").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    print(value)
                })
            }

        })

    }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, what if I want to show the user and not the user details? Thanks