# Display all GeoFire locations stored in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, geofire

As someone new to the above, I am struggling to use the location details stored in Firebase to display all user co-ordinates within Google Maps. Currently, the app displays the user, and no-one else.

I have looked at these questions:

[How to query nearest users in Firebase with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091994/how-to-query-nearest-users-in-firebase-with-swift)

[GeoFire Swift 3 - Saving and Updating Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726744/geofire-swift-3-saving-and-updating-coordinates)

[Firebase Retrieving Data in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759614/firebase-retrieving-data-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But unlike these, I only log the actual locations (for now), and am not interested in showing locations within a radius, but rather all those stored.

Below is the main section:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let lat = location?.coordinate.latitude
    let long = location?.coordinate.longitude

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user_locations")
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref)
    geoFire.setLocation(location!, forKey: deviceUID) //using device ID as yet to add users

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (lat)!, longitude:(long)!, zoom:14)
    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)

}
```

And this is what I've considered in `locationManager`, but don't know how to apply, or use without a radius:

```
    let center = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
    let circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: 5)

    _ = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
    print("Key '\(key)' in area at location '\(location)'")
```

Any help would be appreciated.